# Unknown data source

Tags: c#, reportviewer

A data source instance has not been supplied for the datasource 'dataset1'. this appears in my report viewer.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet1 dataSet = new DataSet1();

        DataTable table = dataSet.Tables.Add("Language");
        table.Columns.Add("A1", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        table.Columns.Add("A2", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        table.Columns.Add("A3", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        DataRow row;

        row = table.NewRow();
        row["A1"] = textBox1.Text;
        row["A2"] = textBox2.Text;
        row["A3"] = textBox3.Text;
        table.Rows.Add(row);

       //table.Fill(dataSet, "Language");
       // MyReport.ProcessingMode = MyReport.Local;
       MyReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
       MyReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DT", dataSet.Tables[1]));
      // MyReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource());
       //MyReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DT", table));
       MyReport.LocalReport.Refresh();
       MyReport.RefreshReport();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table is actually on index 0, not 1. And if the report requires DataSet named "dataset1" make sure you name it like that.

Change this.

```
MyReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DT", dataSet.Tables[1]));
```

To this:

```
MyReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dataset1", dataSet.Tables[0]));
```

Plus you don't need to create a `DataSet` in order to just add a `DataTable` to it and the pass it by its index. You can create a separate `DataTable` and that's it:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("Language");
...
...
MyReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dataset1", table));
```

Comment: thank u for ur help but i face another problem after i write ur code in my project and this error is   "an error eccurred  during local report proccessing "

Comment: thank u@Taosique for ur help but i faced another problem when i write ur answor code in my code  the error is " An error occurred during your local report proccessing"                                    finally  need it soon explain step by step on reportViewer not Cristalreport without database

make it from some controls(2 textbox , 1 datetimpeaker , 1Compobox) without database i need it today pls if u can and  I appreciate your favor